# RestSharp custom IDeserialize return generic type

Tags: c#, json, generics, windows-phone-8.1, restsharp

I would like to write custom deserializer class by implementing `RestSharp.Portable.Deserializers.IDeserialize` interface:

```
        public class EnrollmentDeserializer : IDeserializer
        {
            public T Deserialize<T> (IRestResponse response) 
            {
                if (response.IsSuccess)
                {
                    IList<Enrollment> enrollments = new List<Enrollments>();
                    // parsing JObjects and JTokens into list of enrollments
                    return (T)enrollments;
                }
                throw new Exception(response.StatusCode + ": can't get enrollments");
            }
        }
```

Mine problem is about generic type `T`. How can I define `T` to return `IList<Enrollment>` without casting?

I tried '`where T : List<Enrollment>`' or '`where T : class`', but none of these works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to do the wrong use of generics. The purpose is to reuse the same piece of code for "any" (or many) types.

In your case, you can extend the default implementation. Then if type is the one you want, use your implementation. If not, call base method.

Hope I've helped.